# t-sql Convert comma separated string into int, without using user created function

Tags: t-sql

I'm passing a list of int's (comma separated)

ie. `1, 2, 3, 4`

to my sp.  But I'm getting an error because the list is a string, and I'm comparing to an int field.  Is there a way for me to convert the list to int, without using a user created function?

Note: employeeID is INT

```
declare @intArray varchar(200)

SELECT *
FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE employeeID IN ( @intArray )
```

The error is "Cannot convert type varchar to int"

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And are you able to change the code that's calling your sp?

Comment: @Damien SQL Server 2005.  Yes I'm able to change code calling my sp.

Comment: rats. For 2008, I'd suggest changing to using table valued parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't want to cast that list into an int, but into a list of ints.

There is no cast operator or function for that, but you can use dynamic SQL to get around it.

Basically you write

```
EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM tbl_Employee WHERE employeeID IN ('+@intArray+')')
```

Be aware of SQL injection attacks though!

Comment: This is a good native way of doing what the OP wants. Keep in mind that as the list of employees and `ID`s grows, the `IN` phrase become increasingly ineffective. In 2005/2008, `EXISTS` is preferred. Also, dynamic SQL can't be cached, so the execution never gets faster as it does with other statements.

Comment: @Brad: Dynamic statements get cached as well as any other. As long as you don't change the query text, the cached plan is taken. Of course, different ID-lists here would be a problem if the query is executed very frequently. EXISTS would require some (temporary) table to store the searched IDs in. If you just have the list (i.e. from a web app where the user can select certain employees with checkboxes), IN is still you best option.

Comment: I agree that `EXISTS` is not exactly practical here, I simply wanted to point out that it is *preferred* if the table or `IN` list is large. That is good to learn that SQL does cache plans for dynamic SQL (for each change). But I think this caching is largely discountable since the query will change frequently. If not, why would you choose to use dynamic SQL?

Comment: I hate turning everything red :-(  I was hoping there would be another way.  Thanks for your input though.  It's the correct answer in the end lol.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using sql server 2016 and above then use STRING_SPLIT

```
declare @intArray varchar(200)
Set @intArray = '3,4,6,7'

SELECT *
FROM tbl_Employee
WHERE employeeID IN (select * from STRING_SPLIT(@intArray, ','))
```

Comment: Not only your SQL Server should be 2016, also the `compatibility_level` should be 130 or upper. Read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47206082/4344976).

Comment: this one is working. its also a sure short solution. working in my  case

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to convert not only a `string` to `int`, but **several** `int`s into **one**. Do you expect that your `SELECT` will return all employee's with and ID listed in the array?

I realize that you wanted to do this **without** a function. However, this is how I currently do it and it works great. Take what you will from my answer.

This code uses a `while` loop which could likely be improved to a recursive CTE if you are in SQL 2005/2008. You can use the output of the function as a table that you `INNER JOIN` to which will allow you to filter very quickly.

```
/*
************************************************************************************************************************
    Name:           ConvertDelimitedListIntoTable
    Description:    Converts a list of delimited values into a table for use like a dynamic IN statment

    Modification History
    Date        Author          Description
    ==========  ============    ====================================
    2009-01-31  B. Williams     Initial Creation

************************************************************************************************************************
*/
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertDelimitedListIntoTable] (
     @list NVARCHAR(MAX) ,@delimiter CHAR(1) )
RETURNS @table TABLE ( 
     item VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @pos INT ,@nextpos INT ,@valuelen INT

        SELECT  @pos = 0 ,@nextpos = 1

        WHILE @nextpos > 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @nextpos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@list,@pos + 1)
                SELECT  @valuelen = CASE WHEN @nextpos > 0 THEN @nextpos
                                         ELSE LEN(@list) + 1
                                    END - @pos - 1
                INSERT  @table ( item )
                VALUES  ( CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(@list,@pos + 1,@valuelen)) )
                SELECT  @pos = @nextpos

            END

        DELETE  FROM @table
        WHERE   item = ''

        RETURN 
    END
```

Use:

```
DECLARE @intArray varchar(200)

SELECT *
FROM  tbl_Employee e
      INNER JOIN dbo.ConvertDelimitedListIntoTable(@intArray,',') arr
                 ON e.EmployeeID = arr.Item
```

---

There may also be a quick way to do this with a `tally` table.

Comment: Didn't manage to make first solution work in stored procedure.
Thanks for this one !

Comment: The brief said not to use a function - though i like your solution not really helpful to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of, Create user defined SQL function:

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CustomStringSplit]
(
@Line nvarchar(MAX),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5) = '|'
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
Data nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
IF @Line IS NULL RETURN

```
DECLARE @split_on_len INT = LEN(@SplitOn)
DECLARE @start_at INT = 1
DECLARE @end_at INT
DECLARE @data_len INT

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    SET @end_at = CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@Line,@start_at)
    SET @data_len = CASE @end_at WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@Line) ELSE @end_at-@start_at END
    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data) VALUES( SUBSTRING(@Line,@start_at,@data_len) );
    IF @end_at = 0 BREAK;
    SET @start_at = @end_at + @split_on_len
END

RETURN
```

END