# Incorrect return value from TSQL stored procedure to VB 6

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, vb6

I have an sql stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Test_ListProcessSQL]

@LocationIDs as varchar(max) =''

AS 

BEGIN

    IF EXISTS(SELECT  dbo.Locations.LocationID FROM dbo.Locations where  LocationID in (@LocationIDs))
        Return 0
    ELSE
        Return 1
END
```

when i run it like this:

usp_Test_ListProcessSQL 2478

it returns 0

but when i run it from VB 6 code, It returns 1

```
Public Function TestListProcessSQL(lLocationId As String) As Integer
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command, prm As ADODB.Parameter

    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_Test_ListProcessSQL_True"


    With cmd
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("return_value", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@LocationIDs", adBSTR, adParamInput, , lLocationId)
    End With

    cmd.Execute
    TestListProcessSQL = cmd.Parameters("return_value")

End Function
```

Please suggest why code is returning wrong/different value

Comment: You're making a classic mistake (by the look of things) of assuming that a *single* string that *contains* commas is, in any way, going to be treated the same as *multiple* values *separated* by commas. There are plenty of questions on here about parameterizing `IN`, if you'd care to search for them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am testing this sp with same input parameter but result is different from VB6 app vs SQL query window

Comment: You may be trying it with just one value (for now) but the fact that you've given your parameter a plural name, and you're using it in an `IN` clause indicate that you're going down the wrong route - you're going to have to restructure your stored procedure *anyway* to accommodate multiple values, there's not much point spending time fixing it for the *one* scenario where it may work.

Comment: I think maybe this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471449/t-sql-convert-comma-seperated-string-into-int-without-using-user-created-functi