# How to separate string by comma using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wants to separate string by comma. Actually I wants to filter in `WHERE` Clause like

```
CREATE PROC spGetRecords
@class varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM SampleTable
    WHERE class in (@class)  --in Database class is an integer
END
```

So, I want to pass the parameter when execute query like below

```
spGetRecords @class = '12,22,45,66'
```

I think it's not possible to pass multiple value in single parameter in my case.

So, If I remove separate the string by `','` then I can run my query in while loop that will bring the record correct?

So, How can I separate the string by **comma**

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL:  `exec 'select ...'`

Comment: @Igor `Microsoft sql server 2012 11.0.2100.60`

Comment: @juergend what it will make sense?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server **2008** or newer, you should use **table-valued parameter** which is the *proper* and most efficient way of doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try splitting using xml path as below:

```
Declare @delimiter nvarchar(max) = ','
Declare @str nvarchar(max) = '12,22,45,66'

Declare @xml as xml
        Select @xml = CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(@str,@delimiter,'$$$SSText$$$') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'$$$SSText$$$','</x><x>')+ '</x>' AS XML) 

--select @xml
Select y.value(N'text()[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') as value 
FROM @xml.nodes(N'x') as x(y)
```

If you are in SQL Server >= 2016 you can use STRING_SPLIT() as below:

```
Select * from string_split('12,22,45,66',',')
```

Comment: your answer is correct. But before I give correct, can you give explanation about third and 4th line?. thanks

Comment: Try selecting individual lines you will understand, first step converting into xml using xml path, while create nodes i am changing comma/delimiter as separate node and second line traversing thru all nodes

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL

```
exec 'SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE class in (' + @class + ')'
```

which will patch the strings together and then execute it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable WHERE class in (12,22,45,66)
```

Comment: class is an integer

Comment: it's a multilne query, not single line. For giving an example only I mentioned sample table.. But actually it is little bit lengthy query

Comment: So? Just put it in a string like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution - [Converting String List into Int List in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663789/converting-string-list-into-int-list-in-sql) . Idea here is to send in an int list to a stored procedure as an XML parameter.

Here is another quick but dirty solution - [t-sql Convert comma separated string into int, without using user created function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471449/t-sql-convert-comma-separated-string-into-int-without-using-user-created-functi) . Here the passed in value is used within a dynamic sql statement.

More ideas - http://sql-articles.com/scripts/function-to-split-comma-separated-string-to-integer/