# SQL Server 2016, Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split

In SQL Server 2016 I receive this error with [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) function

```
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT('a,b,c',',')
```

Error:

> Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: Check the compatibility level of the database you are running it from. You may have it set lower.

Comment: Make sure that the database compatibility level is 130.

Comment: There's a [big honking blue box in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) concerning this topic.

Comment: @JeroenMostert +1 for use of the word "honking" :)

Comment: Life's too short to read documentation :)

Comment: All - Not necessarily. If using a case sensitive COLLATION, the function is actually LOWER CASE ("string_split"). This is extremely frustrating because Microsoft's documentation lists these types of functions in ALL_CAPPS even though, in a case sensitive database, that will fail with the error the OP describes.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Make sure that the database compatibility level is **130**

you can use the following query to change it:

```sql
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can check the current compatibility level of a database using the following command:

```sql
SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Your-Database-Name';
```

Comment: "Simple, just change the gravitational constant of the universe"  (permissions denied)

Comment: what if my sql server justo allow me 100,90 & 110 whitchshould i use?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim then you cannot use `STRING_SPLIT` function. You can build your own function. check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: Check your database compatibility by `SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Your-Database-Name';`

Comment: My mistake was to add single quote around my database name, e.g. `['DatabaseName']`, and you'll get error message "User does not have permission to alter database". Remember **DO NOT** add the single quote. Correct way: `[DatabaseName]` and you will be able to set the compatibility level

Comment: Not necessarily. If using a case sensitive COLLATION, the function is actually LOWER CASE ("string_split"). This is extremely frustrating because Microsoft's documentation lists these types of functions in ALL_CAPPS even though, in a case sensitive database, that will fail with the error the OP describes.

Answer (score 11):

I was using `Split_string`, which felt grammatically correct in English, but my old eyes didn't see that it should be `STRING_SPLIT` ... so, if you're a bit mentally challenged like me, then check you've typed the command the right way! :)

Answer (score 4):

If you can't change the COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL of the database you are working in, you can try looking at other databases on the same server to find one with a higher COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL.  I found that the "master" database on my target server was at COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140, so I *connected* to that database, and then executed my query, which actually ran against (fully qualified) tables in other databases on the server whose COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL was less than 130.  It worked! Just query the various databases on your server with

```
SELECT compatibility_level  FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<database_name>';
```

to find one that is >= 130.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Compatibility Level of your Database.
to do so try below Query and Change you compatibility level to 150.

ALTER DATABASE [Database_Name] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150

Comment: SQL Server 2016 does not have compatibility level  150. It is limited to 130 there and Yahfoufi answer is correct

Comment: You should change the compatibility level value to 140 if you want to set your database compatibility to SQL Server 2017.

Answer (score -1):

STRING_SPLIT is not a valid command for your SQL version and altering database might be very risky. Below can be used with both old and new version of SQL Servers and their databases. I know it is a big query but gets the job done without problem.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(1024)
DECLARE @Pos int
DECLARE @Keywords TABLE(string varchar(25)) 
DECLARE @Key varchar(25)
SET @String = 'a,b,c'
SET @Pos = 1
WHILE (@Pos > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Pos = PATINDEX('%,%', @String)
    SET @Key = SUBSTRING(@String, 0, @Pos)
    IF (@Pos = 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Keywords (string) VALUES(@String)
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Keywords (string) VALUES(@Key)
        END
    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @Pos+1, (SELECT LEN(@String)))
END 

SELECT * FROM @Keywords
```

Comment: Another user suggested changing `@Pos` to `@Pos+1` in the second substring operation, and I agree. This would allow the delimiter to be other than a space - e.g., `'%,%'` instead of `'% %'`. The `LTRIM()` would then be unnecessary. Whether or not the split values should be trimmed and/or empty values discarded should really be separate from the split.  See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uXHADTcN).