# Compare Two Strings For Common Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to compare two strings and find a common value between the two? For example, `'Alpha Bravo'` and `'Echo Charlie Bravo Delta'` have a common word which is `'Bravo'`.

In my scenario, I have two tables sharing the similar formatted words (i.e. Alpha Bravo Charlie Delta Echo) in a column and I would like to find whether a similarity in word(s) exist so a condition is met.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: The commas don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DB version is 2016+, then you can create queries containing `STRING_SPLIT()` function with `CROSS APPLY` next to each of your tables, and then filter common values through `INTERSECT` operator :

```
SELECT value
  FROM tab1  
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(str, ' ')
INTERSECT
SELECT value
  FROM tab2 
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(str, ' ')
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8a6a8741d9b4b3beb20e4bdacb172a87)</kbd>

which yields case-insensitive matching among splitted words.

Comment: STRING_SPLIT does not work on sql server, it says invalid object

Comment: Hi @Stefano I showed in the demo that works, but for version 2016, seems you have a former version.

Comment: for anyone who stumbles on this same problem, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205829/sql-server-2016-invalid-object-name-string-split

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I strongly advise against deploying anything like this in production, unless your tables are extremely small. But it's worth posting because it may help you find a proper solution.

`SPLIT_STRING` returns a one-column table (the column name is `[value]`), which contains the list of words (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). This column is joined with the first table using LIKE (see the CROSS APPLY block).

```
-- Declare test tables
DECLARE @TABLE1 table([TEXT] varchar(1000))
DECLARE @TABLE2 table([TEXT] varchar(1000))

-- Populate tables
INSERT INTO @TABLE1
VALUES ('alpha bravo charlie'), ('delta echo lima'), ('golf hotel india'), ('tango uniform victor')

INSERT INTO @TABLE2
VALUES ('alpha lima'), ('tango')

-- Query
SELECT DISTINCT T1.[TEXT]
FROM @TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN @TABLE2 T2 ON 1 = 1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT([T2].[TEXT], ' ') T3 WHERE T1.[TEXT] LIKE '%' + T3.value + '%') AS T3
```