# Search a table using a list of strings in EF Core 8 preview (where in clause)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

** UPDATE 2 **
The issue ended up being the database compatibility level.  Setting the level on the context did nothing as it needed be set on the database itself for it to work.  There is a breaking changes note with EF 8 [Breaking Changes in EF 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#high-impact-changes)

In my case I'm on 2019 SQL Server, but the compatibility level was set to 100 which behaves like SQL Server 2008.  It must have taken that from a restored backup.

To quote the note:

> Old behavior Previously, when the Contains operator was used in LINQ
> queries with a parameterized value list, EF generated SQL that was
> inefficient but worked on all SQL Server versions.
>
> New behavior Starting with EF Core 8.0, EF now generates SQL that is
> more efficient, but is unsupported on SQL Server 2014 and below.
>
> Note that newer SQL Server versions may be configured with an older
> compatibility level, also making them incompatible with the new SQL.
> This can also occur with an Azure SQL database which was migrated from
> a previous on-premises SQL Server instance, carrying over the old
> compatibility level.

** UPDATE **
So I took the suggestion below and set the compatibility level to 150 (SQL Server 2019) as it was set at 100 and reran the code and it resulted with the same issue.  Next step is to set it correctly in the Server.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<RIEDBContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RIEDB"),
                 o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(150)));
```

Log verifies the compatibility level

```
2023-09-29 09:10:07.638 -04:00 [DBG] Entity Framework Core 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.6 initialized 'RIEDBContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:8.0.0-rc.1.23419.6' with options: CompatibilityLevel=150
```

Same Stack Trace in the log

```
2023-09-29 09:11:23.390 -04:00 [DBG] Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__ReasonCodesList_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [r].[ReasonCodeID], [r].[ApplicationStatusCode], [r].[BenefitTypeCode], [r].[IsActive], [r].[ReasonCodes], [r].[ReasonLongDescription], [r].[ReasonShortDescription]
FROM [ReasonCode] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[ReasonCodes] IN (
    SELECT [r0].[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@__ReasonCodesList_0) WITH ([value] varchar(6) '$') AS [r0]
)
2023-09-29 09:11:23.438 -04:00 [ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (49ms) [Parameters=[@__ReasonCodesList_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [r].[ReasonCodeID], [r].[ApplicationStatusCode], [r].[BenefitTypeCode], [r].[IsActive], [r].[ReasonCodes], [r].[ReasonLongDescription], [r].[ReasonShortDescription]
FROM [ReasonCode] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[ReasonCodes] IN (
    SELECT [r0].[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@__ReasonCodesList_0) WITH ([value] varchar(6) '$') AS [r0]
)
2023-09-29 09:11:23.451 -04:00 [ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'RIE.Models.DBModels.RIEDBContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'.
```

** ORIGINAL POST **

I'm upgrading an existing EF 6 project to EF Core using the EF 8 preview 8.0.0-rc.1.23419.6 release.

I am getting an Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'. for something that seems pretty basic.

I pass a basic list of strings via WebAPI, the strings are passed correctly and the List parameter looks correct in the method call in debug.

Really not sure what the issue is here.

Entity (Navigation properties removed)

```
public partial class ReasonCode
{
    public int ReasonCodeID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationStatusCode { get; set; } = null!;
    public string ReasonCodes { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? ReasonShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string? ReasonLongDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string BenefitTypeCode { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Calling Method

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ReasonCode>> GetReasonsByCodesAsync(List<string> ReasonCodesList)
{
    var dbResult = await _context.ReasonCodes.Where(e => ReasonCodesList.Contains(e.ReasonCodes)).ToListAsync();
    return dbResult;
}
```

Controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GetReasonsByCodes")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetReasonsByCodes([FromBody] List<string> ReasonCodesList)
{
    var searchResult = await _reasonCodeRepository.GetReasonsByCodesAsync(ReasonCodesList);

    if ((searchResult == null) || (!searchResult.Any())) return NotFound();
    return Ok(searchResult);
}
```

Entity creation from OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ReasonCode>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("ReasonCode");

    entity.HasIndex(e => e.ReasonCodes, "UQ__ReasonCo__8CCF3D98662BF692").IsUnique();

    entity.Property(e => e.ApplicationStatusCode)
        .HasMaxLength(2)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.BenefitTypeCode)
        .HasMaxLength(2)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.ReasonCodes)
        .HasMaxLength(6)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.ReasonLongDescription)
        .HasMaxLength(600)
        .IsUnicode(false);
    entity.Property(e => e.ReasonShortDescription)
        .HasMaxLength(100)
        .IsUnicode(false);

    entity.HasOne(d => d.ApplicationStatusCodeNavigation).WithMany(p => p.ReasonCodes)
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.ApplicationStatusCode)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.ApplicationStatusCode)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK__ReasonCod__Appli__5D61A667");
});
```

This is the error I get in the Log File. It looks like it wanted to do the right thing, but seems that it didn't iterate the List for some reason.

```
2023-09-28 14:00:52.078 -04:00 [ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (42ms) [Parameters=[@__ReasonCodesList_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT [r].[ReasonCodeID], [r].[ApplicationStatusCode], [r].[BenefitTypeCode], [r].[IsActive], [r].[ReasonCodes], [r].[ReasonLongDescription], [r].[ReasonShortDescription]
FROM [ReasonCode] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[ReasonCodes] IN (
    SELECT [r0].[value]
    FROM OPENJSON(@__ReasonCodesList_0) WITH ([value] varchar(6) '$') AS [r0]
)
```

Full stack trace

```
2023-09-28 14:00:52.091 -04:00 [ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'RIE.Models.DBModels.RIEDBContext'.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:73e5670f-2c5b-4e05-8b86-3ac42e5d188c
Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
ClientConnectionId:73e5670f-2c5b-4e05-8b86-3ac42e5d188c
Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15
2023-09-28 14:00:52.163 -04:00 [INF] Executed action RIE.Services.Controllers.LookupController.GetReasonsByCodes (RIE.Services) in 6474.8297ms
2023-09-28 14:00:52.164 -04:00 [INF] Executed endpoint 'RIE.Services.Controllers.LookupController.GetReasonsByCodes (RIE.Services)'
2023-09-28 14:00:52.165 -04:00 [ERR] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__209_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at RIE.DataImpl.Repositories.ReasonCodeRepository.GetReasonsByCodesAsync(List`1 ReasonCodesList) in C:\Users\segantim\source\repos\RIE\RIE.DataImpl\Repositories\ReasonCodeRepository.cs:line 30
   at RIE.Services.Controllers.LookupController.GetReasonsByCodes(List`1 ReasonCodesList) in C:\Users\segantim\source\repos\RIE\RIE.Services\Controllers\LookupController.cs:line 139
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|7_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Looks like `ReasonCodes` configured to be mapped to JSON, do you have entity type configuration you are not showing?

Comment: The entity was reverse engineered from the database.  Not sure why it thinks its JSON as I haven't had issues anywhere else.  Not sure where I should look as I'm not an EF guru by any means. I'll edit this to show the controller call...

Comment: Check out the `OnModelCreating` method in your db context.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is other way around. Seems that it tries to serialize `ReasonCodesList` as JSON and process it as one - `OPENJSON(@__ReasonCodesList_0)`. TBH do not have the SQL Server available ATM, looks like a translation bug to me - worth opening an issue at github

Comment: Also what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SqlServer 15.0.4153.1 (Server 2019)

Comment: Github issue posted at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31898

Comment: What's your compatibility level of your database? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73192597/14868997 for a better bulk solution using a Table Valued Parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments to your GitHub post, this is [an issue with the version and compatibility level](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/31362#issuecomment-1652920760) of your database. [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) using `WITH` only works on level 130 or higher.

So either upgrade your database **(recommended)**, or tell EF Core that you are using a lower compatibility level:

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(110));
```

There is a much better option anyway for doing bulk queries: use a Table Valued Parameter [as I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73192597/14868997).

Comment: Thanks, going to research it as the compatibility level is currently 100.  Frustrating since I asked the DBA's to specifically leave it at the server.  We had checked it when we went live, but somehow it is reverted now.  It's going to take a few days to get it done.  Primary goal was getting it working, then upgrading.  I did do the async, but haven't really kept up with all the new features, Thanks for pointing that out. I did see the bulk query thing, but dismissed it for some reason.  I will revisit it.

Comment: I think definite "citation needed" for TVPs being "much better". Are you just assuming this or have you seen stats from someone actually measuring this in realistic real world scenarios? You may be correct but I've not seen stats backing this up any where

Comment: No I don't have definitive stats, but I'd guess shredding any seriously large JSON is going to take time, whereas TVPs are already in tabular format. Plus they do get cardinality statistics, primary keys and check constraints, which `OPENJSON` does not.

Comment: But they don't get into tabular format by magic. They get into tabular format because work happens up front to get them into data pages in tempdb in row format. And if these values are only needed for a single use I don't think it is self evident that this is overall going to be any quicker than just streaming through a string and emitting values

Comment: But they are transmitted to SQL Server already as rows (using the Bulk Insert TDS protocol) so there isn't much work to do other than write the data into tempdb (which is kept as much as possible in memory these days, unless too many pages). Equally a JSON blob larger than 512kb would end up getting written to tempdb also as well as getting synchronously deallocated as opposed to the usual deferred drop https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/315189/220697