# EF Core error Incorrect syntax near '$' but EF Core generated the query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

Using .NET 8 RC2 and EF Core

I created a dynamic query and executed the query which results in the following error

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '$'.
Incorrect syntax near '$'.
Incorrect syntax near '$'.
```

If I run `.ToQueryString()` to see the query generated I get this.

```
DECLARE @__startDate_0 smalldatetime = '2023-10-26T00:00:00';
DECLARE @__endDate_1 smalldatetime = '2023-10-26T00:00:00';
DECLARE @__siteNos_2 nvarchar(4000) = N'[15,42,56,74,89,98,102,104,109,113,114,115,116,118,120,121,122,123,124,124,125,127,128,129,130,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,156,157,158,159,161,162,163,164,165,167,169,170,171,172,173,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,199,200,201,202,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,295,296,296,297,300,301,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,328,331,333,334,335,338,339,340,341,342,343]';
DECLARE @__startTime_3 time = '07:00:00';  
DECLARE @__endTime_4 time = '22:00:00';  
DECLARE @__upperLimit_5 smallint = CAST(30000 AS smallint);  
DECLARE @__lowerLimit_6 smallint = CAST(0 AS smallint);
DECLARE @__stationIds_7 nvarchar(4000) = N'[117,116,98]';
DECLARE @__courseIds_8 nvarchar(4000) = N'[7]';

SELECT [o].[order_no], [o].[Bumped], [o].[Check_no], [o].[checkback], [o].[Course], [o].[Expoed], [o].[item_count], [o].[manual_hold], [o].[ODate], [o].[Order_DateTime], [o].[Order_Index], [o].[Server_no], [o].[Site_no], [o].[StartTime], [o].[Station_no], [o].[Table_no]
FROM [Orders] AS [o]
WHERE [o].[Order_DateTime] IS NOT NULL AND CONVERT(date, [o].[Order_DateTime]) >= @__startDate_0 AND CONVERT(date, [o].[Order_DateTime]) <= @__endDate_1 AND [o].[Site_no] IN (
SELECT [s].[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@__siteNos_2) WITH ([value] smallint '$') AS [s]  
) AND [o].[item_count] > CAST(0 AS tinyint) AND CONVERT(time, [o].[Order_DateTime]) >= @__startTime_3 AND CONVERT(time, [o].[Order_DateTime]) <= @__endTime_4 AND [o].[Expoed] <= @__upperLimit_5 AND [o].[Expoed] >= @__lowerLimit_6 AND CAST([o].[Station_no] AS smallint) NOT IN (
SELECT [s0].[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@__stationIds_7) WITH ([value] smallint '$') AS [s0]
 ) AND CAST([o].[Course] AS smallint) IN (
SELECT [c].[value]
FROM OPENJSON(@__courseIds_8) WITH ([value] smallint '$') AS [c]
)
```

I can see the '$' which I am assuming EF Core is complaining about but EF core generated the query so how would I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility level in your database? Use `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(...));` to set matching one for EF.

Comment: @GuruStron Where and what am I checking? The code was working fine in .Net 7

Comment: Just looking up the breaking changes as I have missed something regarding this

Comment: `SELECT compatibility_level 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'mydbname';`

Comment: Yep just seen, need to look up what this all means as the server is 2019 but I see some databases are 110 and newer ones we created are 150

Comment: Post your EF Code in the question itself. I see some quirks like `CONVERT(date, [o].[Order_DateTime]) >= @__startDate_0` which can harm performance. While the server will use any indexes on `Order_DateTime`, it won't be able to use the statistics to determine how many values may be returned, and end up creating an inefficient execution plan. I suspect you used `OrderDate.Date >=someDate`. Use `c.OrderDate >=somedate.Date && c.OrderDate <someDate.Date.AddDays(1)` instead. This will avoid any conversions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF Code is a bit much to post as its part of a reporting system., but I can paste that part you are interested in.  `x.OrderDateTime.Value.Date >= startDate`. `OrderDateTime` is nullable and `startDate` is declared else where but is just a parameter. I do a `.HasValue` on `OrderDateTime` before this code.

Comment: You don't need `HasValue` at all, the comparison to a value will eliminate nulls. I've built a Blazor reporting site that calls an OData service backed by EF Core too. `x.OrderDateTime >=somedate.Date && x.OrderDateTime <someDate.Date.AddDays(1)` will produce a simpler query that returns the same results and a better execution plan.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Really? I am sure I had an issue before where it was complaining the value was null. I will remove it again give it a go.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just removed as you said and wrote it like you said, the generated query is still the same apart from it does not check for null `CONVERT(date, [o].[Order_DateTime]) >= @__startDate_0 AND CONVERT(date, [o].[Order_DateTime]) <= @__endDate_1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search a table using a list of strings in EF Core 8 preview (where in clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77197688/search-a-table-using-a-list-of-strings-in-ef-core-8-preview-where-in-clause)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is due to breaking change in the query translation for EF Core 8 - see [`Contains` in LINQ queries may stop working on older SQL Server versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#contains-in-linq-queries-may-stop-working-on-older-sql-server-versions).

Check the compatibility level of the database:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'mydbname';
```

> I see some databases are 110 and newer ones we created are 150

Pass the values to the context options (when registering in DI with `AddDbContext` for example):

```
opts
   .UseSqlServer(@"<CONNECTION STRING>", o => o.UseCompatibilityLevel(110)) // or 150
```

See the [Mitigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/breaking-changes#mitigations) part of the breaking change doc.

Also I would argue that you should consider upgrading the database (and server if needed) to support new features (see [`ALTER DATABASE SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16)).

Comment: Thanks for this, will look into upgrading the compatibility of these databases but for now use your fix.

Answer (score 3):

If your level of compatibilty on the database is just low because of some historical reasons, but you are actually running SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can do:

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 140;
```

Would solve the problem at the root without changing code in - how many? - projects.

Comment: This is already mentioned in the existing answer why an extra one?

Comment: Wanted to give more details about needed compatibility level and SQL server version.